# How to download the *.jar file from http:// seleniumhq.org using selenium WebDriver code?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Steps**:  open the Browser > enter URL http://seleniumhq.org  > 
 Click Download tab > click Download version “2.46.0” link
It opens a dialog window. Click “Save File” button

**Note**: I have tried download *.xls file example code from URL: http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-download-a-file-with-webdriver it is working fine in my system. It automatically handling the dialog box and saving the file in destination location.

But the same code not working to download the *.jar file.
Could you please look into this one and help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are downloading Selenium Standalone Server try this:

```
 profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/java-archive");
```

If downloading selenium java webdriver:

```
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip");
```

Here is a nice link for a detailed list of file format MIME type list: [ClickME](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)